# JavaFx Application usign MVC

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller

I have implemented three Java classes for my application, two of which serve as Controller Classes. One of these controllers is responsible for managing a TableView, while the other acts as a CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) interface, allowing users to add, delete, or update data.

To initially populate the TableView, I've added three random objects, and this part works as expected. However, when I transition to the CRUD scene, add a new object, and return to the TableView, I encounter an issue. The new object doesn't appear in the TableView, even when using 'System.out.println' (SOUT) for debugging.

Surprisingly, when I use 'System.out.println' in the CRUD controller, I can see that the new object is indeed being created. It's puzzling why the TableView doesn't display the new data.

This discrepancy between the CRUD controller and the TableView controller has left me searching for a solution. Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

These is my code:

```
package com.example.assigment1;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TaskManager {
private ObservableList\<Task\> tasks;

    public TaskManager() {
        tasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        tasks.addAll(
                new Task("Task 1", "To do Java Assigment", "Closed"),
                new Task("Task 2", "To do JS Lab2", "Opened"),
                new Task("Task 3", "To do CSS Lab4", "Opened")
        );
    }
    
    // Add a task to the task list
    public void addTask(Task task) {
        tasks.add(task);
    }
    
    // Remove a task from the task list
    public void removeTask(Task task) {
        tasks.remove(task);
    }
    
    // Get the list of tasks
    public ObservableList<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }
    
    public List<Task> getAllTasks() {
        return new ArrayList<>(tasks);
    }
    
    public void printTasks() {
        for (Task task : tasks) {
            System.out.println("Task: " + task.getName() + ", Description: " + task.getDescription() + ", Status: " + task.getStatus());
        }
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.assigment1;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TaskController {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Task> tableView;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Task, String> colName;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Task, String> colDescription;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Task, String> colStatus;

    private TaskManager taskManager;

    public TaskController() {
        taskManager = new TaskManager();
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // Associate the columns with the corresponding properties of the Task class
        colName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
        colDescription.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().descriptionProperty());
        colStatus.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().statusProperty());

        // Set the items of the TableView to your TaskManager's task list
        tableView.setItems(taskManager.getTasks());
    }

    @FXML
    private void onCrudClick() {
        // Load and show the CRUD view
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("crud-view.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            CrudController crudController = loader.getController();
            crudController.setTableView(tableView);  // Pass the reference

            // Create a new stage for the CRUD view
            Stage crudStage = new Stage();
            crudStage.setTitle("CRUD Task");
            crudStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            crudStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @FXML
    private void onRefreshClick() {

        taskManager.printTasks();

    }
}
```

```
package com.example.assigment1;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List;

public class CrudController {

    @FXML
    private TextField fieldName;

    @FXML
    private TextField fieldDescription;

    @FXML
    private TextField fieldStatus;

    @FXML
    private Button buttonInsert;

    @FXML
    private Button buttonView;

    private TaskManager taskManager;

    public CrudController() {
        taskManager = new TaskManager();
    }

    @FXML
    private TableView<Task> tableView;  // Add a reference to the TableView

    public void setTableView(TableView<Task> tableView) {
        this.tableView = tableView;
    }


    @FXML
    private void onInsertClick() {
        // Create a new task and add it to the task manager
        String name = fieldName.getText();
        String description = fieldDescription.getText();
        String status = fieldStatus.getText();

        if (!name.isEmpty() && !description.isEmpty() && !status.isEmpty()) {
            Task newTask = new Task(name, description, status);
            taskManager.addTask(newTask);
            tableView.refresh();

            // Clear the input fields after adding a task
            fieldName.clear();
            fieldDescription.clear();
            fieldStatus.clear();

            // Update the TableView in the TaskController
            if (tableView != null) {
                tableView.setItems(taskManager.getTasks());
                taskManager.printTasks();
            }
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void onViewClick() {
        // Load and display the table view
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("table-view.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            // Create a new stage for the table view
            Stage tableViewStage = new Stage();
            tableViewStage.setTitle("Table View");
            tableViewStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            tableViewStage.show();


            // Close the current CRUD view (optional)
            ((Stage) buttonView.getScene().getWindow()).close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.assigment1;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // Load the FXML file
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("table-view.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        // Set the title of the application window
        stage.setTitle("Task Manager Application");

        // Create a scene using the FXML content
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        // Set the scene for the stage
        stage.setScene(scene);

        // Show the stage
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should *never* have a method on an FXML controller like `setTableView` to set the value of an `@FXML` injected field.  Annotated fields are injected by the loader and should not be changed.

Comment: Your `onViewClick` method loads a new copy of `table-view.fxml` with a new, empty, `TableView`. Your controller classes create new instances of the model class `TaskManager` each time they are instantiated, which is not the usual practice in MV* type architectures. Usually you would have a single model instance and share it with all controllers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx

Comment: James. I solved the issue. Thank you very much!